# Server fails to launch in Google App Engine; OK in Localhost

Tags: mysql, reactjs, google-app-engine, go

I have a Flex App written in Go and React that is deployed to Google App engine. I would like it to interact with a MySql Database (2nd generation) on Google Cloud over a Unix socket. **I believe the issue lies with the Go server not launching/responding to requests (see below for justification).** The App is located at https://haveibeenexploited.appspot.com/

The project is simple. I have two routes in my Server:

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
     "net/http"
     "searchcontract"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./app/build")))
    http.HandleFunc("/search", searchcontract.SearchContract)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The second route ("/search") is activated when a user hits the search button. Ideal behavior should return a row specifying the exploits available for the given "contract address" which React writes out to the screen.
**searchcontract/searchcontract.go**

```
//SearchContract is a handler that queries the DB for compromised contracts.
func SearchContract(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var contractName contractID //Used for parsing in contractName
  queryResult := getRow(&contractName.Name)
  w.WriteHeader(200) 
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(queryResult)
}

//processRow queries the DB for a contract with ID value of name.
func getRow(contractName *string) *ContractVulnerabilityInfo {
var storage ContractVulnerabilityInfo //stores row to encode

//Login to database
...
scanErr := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE ContractAddress=?;", &contractName).Scan(&storage.ContractAddress, &storage.IntegerOverflow, &storage.IntegerUnderflow, &storage.DOS, &storage.ExceptionState, &storage.ExternalCall, &storage.ExternalCallFixed, &storage.MultipleCalls, &storage.DelegateCall, &storage.PredictableEnv, &storage.TxOrigin, &storage.EtherWithdrawal, &storage.StateChange, &storage.UnprotectedSelfdestruct, &storage.UncheckedCall)
...
return &storage
}
```

My `app.yaml` file should allow me to deploy this flex app and does:

```
runtime: go1.12
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.* 
  script: _server # my server.go file handles all endpoints

automatic_scaling:
  max_num_instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5 
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
  # user:password@unix(/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME)/dbname
  MYSQL_CONNECTION: root:root@unix(/cloudsql/haveibeenexploited:us-west1:hibe)/mythril

# https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine
beta_settings:
        cloud_sql_instances: haveibeenexploited:us-west1:hibe
```

I am able to query the database successfully on localhost.[Localhost correctly shows address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZqYu.png)

However, whenever I try to implement and push to AppEngine, when I query something that should be in the database, it does not show up in the remote App! [App Engine does not show address in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3GHP.png). Furthermore, I get a status code of '0' returned, which indicates to me that the server function isn't even being called at all ('200' is what I expect if successful or some other error message.').

**Summary**

I can't wrap my head around this bug. What should work locally should work remotely. Also, I can't debug this app probably because Stackdriver does not support flex apps and the devserver Google Cloud provides does not support Go Apps.

I believe the primary issue is with Go not speaking to the React element correctly or the routing not being taken care of appropriately.

**1) The problem does not lie with MySql connection/database access**
   - I changed my route to only be one page, turned off React, and included a hardcoded query. [The result on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na6JC.png). [The result on App Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz17y.png)

**2) There is an issue in either a) my routing or b) the interaction between React and Go.**
**3) Go seems to start correctly... at least when React is not started.**

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** I believe that the go app indeed is still running, but the searchfunction is failing for whatever reason. The reason I believe this is because when I add another route for `haveibeenexploited.com/hello`, [it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIxIv.png).

Comment: Your example of `SearchContract` and `getRow` omits all error handling, I hope this is only for brevity and your real code actually properly handles errors. If so, how are you handling them? How do you know an error in your code occurred or not? Another thing, from what you're saying I gather that the Go code works correctly but the Reactjs code doesn't... why then show the Go code and leave out the React code? Also what happens if you launch your app on appengine, including react, and then make the query to the server with a tool like postman, bypassing react, do you get the correct result?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you have hardcoded localhost in your reactjs app: https://imgur.com/a/quxXuHW

Comment: @mkopriva .... I think you may be my savior! I apologize... this was a team project I am furthering, so I did not write this code. How would I dynamically get the host it is running on? Or should I hardcode for https://haveibeenexploited.appspot.com/?

And yes, the error handling has been omitted for brevity.

Cerise and mkopriva, there is no log because the log Google Cloud uses is called StackDriver and is not enabled for Go programs. I can't debug really at all, except on localhost and running the server locally to view the errors.

Comment: @mkopriva You make many good points. I think you are right it is probably my react code. I've never looked into postman and have no idea how to use it. Do you have a good link or instruction on how to do this operation?

Comment: @mkopriva I would think though that the localhost hardcoding should be fine though, since it could run on the localhost of AppEngine and receive incoming connections from its localhost:8080?

Comment: You could use environment variables or env specific config files... which one of those depends on google clouds support for them, or maybe GC supports a different and better method of providing env specific configuration that you could use. You will need to do some research on your own as I am not familiar with GC. With react you can probably also provide env specific values during build and embed them in the output file, how exactly you would do that depends on the build tool you are using.

Comment: I’m not an appengine user so I don’t know how it works on localhost. What I know, however, is that an app served from internet, e.g. https://*.appspot.com, making a request to localhost is *not* ok.

Comment: I’m not a postman user either but a lot of people are and so there’s bound to be a lot of tutorials and blog posts on how to use it. Also I’m pretty sure their own documentation is going to be more than decent since they are developer oriented, so I recommend you start on they site if you’re interested. Alternatively, just use curl to see if your server works as it should.

Comment: @mkopriva It works...

You have no idea how overjoyed I am at this fact and how many hours I have put into this simple bug. I ended up using the `console` by viewing the page source and it verifies that the hardcoding of localhost was the issue. I should have done this a long time ago, but somehow confused Google App Engine's lack of debugging to mean I didn't have this option. You not only gave me a solution to my problem but a lot of useful tools. I am indebted to you. Please feel free to add an answer and I would gladly accept it as the best one.